# Change font size in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-size

I am using the following code to change font size of `bodytext` div.  However when I try with a page that has various formattings, and also inside a `<div id="bodytext">` it doesn't work, I don't know why.  It just changes the spacing between lines or something..

**Working script:**

```js
var $affectedElements = $("#bodytext"); // Can be extended, ex. $("div, p, span.someClass")

// Storing the original size in a data attribute so size can be reset
$affectedElements.children().each( function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.data("orig-size", $this.css("font-size") );
});

$("#btn-increase").click(function(){
  changeFontSize(1);
})

$("#btn-decrease").click(function(){
  changeFontSize(-1);
})

$("#btn-orig").click(function(){
  $affectedElements.children().each( function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css( "font-size" , $this.data("orig-size") );
   });
})

function changeFontSize(direction){
    $affectedElements.children().each( function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css( "font-size" , parseInt($this.css("font-size"))+direction );
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-decrease">A-</button>
<button id="btn-orig">A</button>
<button id="btn-increase">A+</button>

<div id="bodytext">
  <p style="font-size : 30px">This text is initially 30px</p>
    <p style="font-size : 20px">This text is initially 20px</p>
    <p style="font-size : 10px">This text is initially 10px</p>
    
  </div>  
</div>
```

**Not working** (that needs to be fixed):

```js
var $affectedElements = $("#bodytext"); // Can be extended, ex. $("div, p, span.someClass")

// Storing the original size in a data attribute so size can be reset
$affectedElements.children().each( function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.data("orig-size", $this.css("font-size") );
});

$("#btn-increase").click(function(){
  changeFontSize(1);
})

$("#btn-decrease").click(function(){
  changeFontSize(-1);
})

$("#btn-orig").click(function(){
  $affectedElements.children().each( function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css( "font-size" , $this.data("orig-size") );
   });
})

function changeFontSize(direction){
    $affectedElements.children().each( function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css( "font-size" , parseInt($this.css("font-size"))+direction );
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="btn-decrease">A-</button>
<button id="btn-orig">A</button>
<button id="btn-increase">A+</button>

<div id="bodytext">

<blockquote>
    <h1 dir="ltr" align="center">
    <span style="font-size: 35pt" lang="ar-sa">title page</span></h1>  
  <p class=MsoNormal dir=ltr style='text-align:justify'><b>
  <font size="5">4. some text: &quot; more text</font></span></b><font size="5"><span
lang=ar-eg> <b>more words</b></span><b>&quot;</span></b></font><b><font size="5">[6].</font></span></b></p>
  <p class=MsoNormal dir=ltr style='text-align:justify'>
  <font size="5">new sentence..................</font>
  <font style="font-size: 18pt" SIZE="5">
  <a style="font-size:18pt;" href="http://example.com/file.html">a link</a></font><font size="5">texttexttext.......</font><font SIZE="5" face="Times New Roman">
  <span lang="AR-EG" style="font-size: 18pt; ">
  <a href="http://www.example.com/file.php">a link</a></span></font><font size="5">words words words words words ..</font></span></p>
  <h2 dir=ltr>&nbsp;</h2>
 <h2 dir=ltr><b><span style="font-size: 22pt; font-style: normal">
 <a name="text">other text</a></span></b></h2>
  <p class=MsoNormal dir=ltr style='text-align:justify'><b>
  <font size="5">&quot;final words....</font></span></b><font size="5"><b>&quot;</span></b></font><b><font size="5">[7].</font></span></b></p>
</blockquote>  
</div>
```

Comment: There are a lot of HTML errors in the 'broken' version. Use an editor with syntax highlighting and you'll see them. I would suggest fixing them first.

Comment: Your code examples are setup to only update the font size on children elements of `#bodytext`.

If a element is more than 2 levels deep within your `<div id="bodytext">` they will not get the new font-sizes applied to them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried through jsfiddle to remove some errors, but the same issue persists: https://jsfiddle.net/0fxqarws/

Comment: @MarioD Even if I changed it to `$affectedElements.each( function(){` and so on, but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the issue is with the `var $affectedElements = $("#bodytext");` selector. This selector is only selecting the `blockquote` element, because it is the only direct sibling of the `#bodytext` element.

This means you are only changing the font size of the `blockquote` element. The dom of a browser has a cascading effect, which CSS adheres to. Therefore if you apply a font size of `13px` to the `blockquote` element, but then apply an inline style further down in the dom to one of the `blockquote` elements siblings then that inline style will take precedence.

What I have done below is add a `*` selector to the `$("#bodytext")` selector, which will select all the elements inside of the `#bodytext`. I have done this to show that the issue is with the selector. However I would recomend thinking of a better way of selecting the specific elements you need or removing the inline styles in the HTML.

NOTE: The only changes I made to the HTML was to clean up the broken tags.

```js
var $affectedElements = $("#bodytext *"); // Can be extended, ex. $("div, p, span.someClass")

// Storing the original size in a data attribute so size can be reset
$affectedElements.children().each( function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.data("orig-size", $this.css("font-size") );
});

$("#btn-increase").click(function(){
  changeFontSize(1);
})

$("#btn-decrease").click(function(){
  changeFontSize(-1);
})

$("#btn-orig").click(function(){
  $affectedElements.children().each( function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css( "font-size" , $this.data("orig-size") );
   });
})

function changeFontSize(direction){
    $affectedElements.children().each( function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css( "font-size" , parseInt($this.css("font-size"))+direction );
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-decrease">A-</button>
<button id="btn-orig">A</button>
<button id="btn-increase">A+</button>

<div id="bodytext">
  
<blockquote>
    <h1 dir="ltr" align="center">
    <span style="font-size: 35pt" lang="ar-sa">title page</span></h1>  
  <p class=MsoNormal dir=ltr style='text-align:justify'><b>
  <font size="5">4. some text: &quot; more text</font></b><font size="5"><span
lang=ar-eg> <b>more words</b></span><b>&quot;</b></font><b><font size="5">[6].</font></b></p>
  <p class=MsoNormal dir=ltr style='text-align:justify'>
  <font size="5">new sentence..................</font>
  <font style="font-size: 18pt" SIZE="5">
  <a style="font-size:18pt;" href="http://example.com/file.html">a link</a></font><font size="5">texttexttext.......</font><font SIZE="5" face="Times New Roman">
  <span lang="AR-EG" style="font-size: 18pt; ">
  <a href="http://www.example.com/file.php">a link</a></span></font><font size="5">words words words words words ..</font></p>
  <h2 dir=ltr>&nbsp;</h2>
 <h2 dir=ltr><b><span style="font-size: 22pt; font-style: normal">
 <a name="text">other text</a></span></b></h2>
  <p class=MsoNormal dir=ltr style='text-align:justify'><b>
  <font size="5">&quot;final words....</font></b><font size="5"><b>&quot;</b></font><b><font size="5">[7].</font></b></p>
  </blockquote>   
</div>
```